# Solve ODE by substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the differential equation by using an appropriate substitution. $(x-y)dx+xdy=0$

So let $y=ux$. Then $dy=xdu+udx$. Plugging in we get $(x-ux)dx+x(xdu+udx)=(x-ux)dx+x^2du+uxdx=xdx+x^2du$

I've got no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $xdx + x^2du=0$, thus either $x=0$ or $$\frac{dx}{x} + du =0 \implies \log|x|+u =c.$$ Since $y=ux$ we have either $y=0$ or  $$y(x) = \frac{c-\log|x|}{x}.$$

Comment: How do you get $\frac{dx}{x}+du=0$?

Comment: $xdx + x^2du = x^2\left(\frac{dx}{x} + du\right)$

Comment: why did you factor out $x^2$ instead of $x$ to get $x(xdu + dx)=0$ ?

Comment: this would give the answer $ux+x=0 \Rightarrow y=-x$

Comment: or am I not allowed to integrate like that?

Comment: You cannot directly integrate $\int xdu$ without proir knowledge of what $x$ is as a function of $u$. However, you can integrate $\int\frac{dx}{x}$. This is why i factored out the $x^2$, after making sure it wasn't zero.

Comment: "You cannot directly integrate ∫xdu without proir knowledge of what x is as a function of u" could you please explain why? Is it because if you have some random variable, call it `w` and you integrate it with respect to some other random variable, call it `v` then it doesn't work? But it's ok for constants?

Comment: What do $dx$ and $du$ mean? and what does it mean to integrate something (call this something $f$) $\int f dx$? I also don't think you mean random variable; that has a particular meaning round here.

Comment: $dx$ and $du$ mean to integrate with respect to $x$ and $u$ so why can't you have $\int x du$ and treat $x$ as a constant?

Comment: If you rearrange the equation; $-xdu = dx$ implies $\frac{dx}{du} =-x$. This is explicitly saying that $x$ is NOT a constant with respect to $u$